# Mongoose Export and Import MongoDB Documents to/from File

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Using JavaScript and Mongoose, I want to export all of the documents of a certain document class to a file (e.g., a JSON or CSV file), and I also want to import (i.e., "load") the contents of such a file into a database. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

From mongoDB docs:

**EXPORT / BACKUP**

To backup data from a mongod instance running on the same machine and on the default port of 27017, use the following command:

```
mongodump
```

You can also specify the --host and --port of the MongoDB instance that the mongodump should connect to. For example:

```
mongodump --host=mongodb.example.net --port=27017
```

mongodump will write BSON files that hold a copy of data accessible via the mongod listening on port 27017 of the mongodb.example.net host. See Create Backups from Non-Local mongod Instances for more information.

To specify a different output directory, you can use the --out or -o option:

```
mongodump --out=/data/backup/
```

**IMPORT / RESTORE**

To use mongorestore to connect to an active mongod, use a command with the following prototype form:

```
mongorestore --port=<port number> <path to the backup>
```

Consider the following example:

```
mongorestore dump-2013-10-25/
```

MongoDB Docs:
[Check](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)